# Why does DateTime.TryParseExact() return different time zone for these input strings?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

I have the simplest method that parses a string to a DateTime **but the return type is DateTimeOffset?**.

I expected the output to be

```
2011-01-11 00:00:00 +01:00
2011-10-11 00:00:00 +01:00
```

but instead it is

```
2011-01-11 00:00:00 +01:00
2011-10-11 00:00:00 +02:00
```

Why do I get this behavior? My test program is below.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Parse("20110111").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(Parse("20111011").ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static DateTimeOffset? Parse(string date)
    {
        DateTime parsedDate;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
        {
            return parsedDate;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is returning `TimeZone` for the current machine and the difference of one hour is due to day light savings. Which are not in effect in October , but they are in January.

Comment: Just to expand on this - the local computer's time zone is being applied at the time that the `parsedDate` variable is implicitly cast from a `DateTime` to a `DateTimeOffset?`, because that's what is declared as the method's return type.